# Commit on parent branch and rebase local branch automatically

Tags: git, git-commit, branching-and-merging

I have a situation like this:

1. I have a main branch `master`, a feature branch `feat` and a fixup branch `fixes`.
2. The `fixes` branch hardcodes some assumptions that make it possible to do local development. (Things like not requiring https or licenses or hardware keys. Stuff that I don't want to accidentally push to prod)
3. I want to stay on `fixes` branch locally but I want to make commits on the `feat` branch.
4. I want the `fixes` branch to always be on top of `feat`.

Assume that this is my current situation:

```
A---B---C <---master
         \
          D---E---F <---feat
                   \
                    G---H <---fixes, HEAD
```

I do some work and make a commit. This is what I want the result to be:

```
A---B---C <---master
         \
          D---E---F---I <---feat
                       \
                        G---H <---fixes, HEAD
```

My idea says that it can be done by first making commit `I` on `fixes` then cherry-picking it on `feat` then resetting `fixes` to `H` then rebasing `fixes` on top of `feat`.

This seems like a lot of work to do manually. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: That operation is carried out like this: `git checkout fixes; git rebase feat`. It could also be carried out with `git rebase feat fixes`

Comment: However, if this is a permanent setup in which you'll forever rebase this branch without ever merging it into something, it's a suboptimal way of dealing with local config. Take a look at `.gitignore` first, and if these files are versioned (and should stay so) there are solutions, like the `--skip-worktree` option of `git update-index`. Don't jump on it immediately though, first be sure it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to stay on fixes branch locally but I want to make commits on the feat branch.

An alternative approach would be to use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), in order to have [a separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) set on `feat`.
You can create I and push it from that folder.

Back to your regular Git repository working tree, checked out on fixes, you can `git rebase feat fixes`.